# Definition of embedded in topology

Tags: general-topology

One of the questions in my topology homework starts with:

Suppose $G$ is a graph and $L \subset G$ is an embedded circle.

I have looked around and found lots of definitions for an 'embedding' but am still a bit confused as to what embedded means. Going by what I have seen for definitions of embedding, does it mean that there exists a homeomorphism from $G$ onto $L$?

Answer (score 0):

It means that there exists a homeomorphism from the circle (which we may as well assume to be the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$) onto $L$ with the topology it inherits as a subspace of $G$.

An example would be a subgraph that looks like a square considered as a graph with four vertices and four edges. More generally, any cycle is an embedded circle.

Answer (score 0):

The definition that I have of an embedding (or imbedding) is this:
Let X,Y be topological spaces, and let f:X -> Y be continuous and injective.
Then, f is an embedding if f^-1: f(X) -> X is continuous.

So, I think that it would mean that there exists an embedding f from G to L.